# Where to make a timestamp and how to reference it after user closes and reopens app

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp

I'm making an app where the user clicks a red button that updates a timestamp to the current time -> button turns green -> the button turns red again 12 hours after the timestamp -> and the cycle continues. Here is my code:

```
var timestampHour = 8
var timestampDay = 30

func getCurrentTime() {

        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        var timeToFirebase = 0
        var timeToDayEnd = 0

        let currentHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
        let currentDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
        //self.nameLabel.text = String(currentHour) + " " + String(currentHour)


        if (currentDay - timestampDay >= 2) {

            self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("timeToWatch").setValue(0)
            self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("streakStatus").setValue("n")

        }

        else if (abs(currentDay - timestampDay) == 1) {

            timeToDayEnd = 24 - timestampHour
            timeToFirebase = timeToDayEnd + currentHour

            if (timeToFirebase >= 12) {

                self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("timeToWatch").setValue(0)
                self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("streakStatus").setValue("n")

            }

            else {

                self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("timeToWatch").setValue(timeToFirebase)

            }


        }

        else {

            timeToFirebase = currentHour - timestampHour
            if (timeToFirebase >= 12) {

                self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("timeToWatch").setValue(0)
                self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("streakStatus").setValue("n")

            }

            else {

                self.ref?.child("users").child(user!).child("timeToWatch").setValue(timeToFirebase)

            }

        }

    }
```

I've been able to figure out how to find time differences between one time and another and act accordingly. However how do I make a timestamp when the user opens the app for the first time only and then update it when the user opens the app 12 hours after the timestamp to the current timestamp? I'm overall confused on how to make a timestamp.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you have a potential bug in your code. The two lines that get the currentHour and currentDay use two separate calls to `Date()`. That means you get the hour from one date and the day from another. There is a very tiny chance that if that code is called at midnight, you could get 23 for the hour and the wrong (next) day. Use a common `Date` instance or get both components in one call instead of two separate calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you need timestamp in unix time format you can use this code:

```
let currentDate = Date()
let timeStamp = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970 //returns something like 1509411424.038336
```

If you need some logic which will store some date, and then will check if 12 hours is passed after storing you can use this code:

```
    func storeDate(_ date: Date) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(date.timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: "storedDate")
    }

    func getStoredDate() -> Date? {
        if let timeStamp = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "storedDate") as? Double {
            return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func checkCurrentDate()-> Bool {
        if let storedDate = getStoredDate() {
            let nextDate = Date(timeInterval: 60 * 60 * 12, since: storedDate)
            if nextDate < Date() {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            storeDate(Date())
            return true
        }
    }
```

If you need to find hours difference between two date you can use this code:

```
let aDate  = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
let bDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 60 * 60 * 12)

let hoursDiff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: aDate, to: bDate).hour ?? 0
```

Comment: I just need hour and day which I have, where do I state the above code?^

Comment: @DannyV, matching of date components (aDay - bDay, aHour - bHour) is really bad practice. You need to match two full dates. For example first date is 2017-01-02 15:00 and second date is 2017-02-01 14:00. In the way you did your logic you will get first date > second date... but this is wrong.

Comment: I see, how exactly would I go about finding the difference between these two dates in hours?

Comment: @Dmitry Since you posted the "better" way to calculate the difference between two dates, you really should remove the poor way.